# Angular Error The selector did not match any elements

Tags: javascript, angular

In an Angular 5 component, I'm getting the error: `Error: The selector "#person-component" did not match any elements.` The thing is that when I inspect the page, the element is there with the right ID. Also, when I load the page from a router link, it works, it's only when I navigate directly to the URL that I get the error.

The element that it can't find is being added by another component, and I'm adding it in the module that contains the parent component. Clearly, something different is happening when I use a link from the main component, but I don't know what that is. The failing line (below) is in `ngAfterContentInit`, so I don't know why it can't find the element.

This is the code that's failing in the component:

```
ngAfterContentInit () {
    ...
    const container = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#person-component');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(container, 'id', htmlId);
    ...
  }
```

Here's how it's being added.

Main component HTML:

```
<employee-component> ...  </employee-component>
```

Sub-component:

```
@Component({
...
selector: 'employee-component',
template: `
    <div id="person-component"></div>
`,
})
```

Here's the element when I inspect the page:

```
<div id="person-component"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show the template?

Comment: @FredrikLundin thx. added more

Comment: Have you tried to use ngAfterViewInit for this?

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtfacd)**

use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngAfterContentInit` :

```
  ngAfterViewInit () {

    const container = this.r.selectRootElement('#person-component');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(container, 'id', htmlId);

  }
```

we use `ngAfterContentInit` to wait for projected Content in `<ng-content>` to be loaded.

Comment: Oh I believe you. It has to be something about the interaction of the components. As I mentioned in my question, it doesn't always fail. If I click a link to the component, it works.

Comment: can you show some code related to this interaction.